# Variation of the square of the Weyl tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, curvature, variational-calculus

After reading a bit about Conformal gravity, I came across the Lagrangian of the form: $$L=C_{abcd}C^{abcd} \sqrt{-g}$$
Where $C$ is the Weyl tensor, I am interested in finding the field equations that arise when considering this Lagrangian for the action.

For this, evaluating the variation of the square of the Weyl tensor is required. But doing so seems like a complicated and long calculation, and I wonder if there is a more clever way of finding it.

I have not managed to find any sources regarding this topic. Any input or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In 4D you could rewrite the spacetime integral of Weyl-squared as something involving the [4D Gauss-Bonnet invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern–Gauss–Bonnet_theorem#Four-dimensional_manifolds) and an integral involving the squares of the Ricci tensor and Ricci scalar.  But that might not be any nicer to vary.

Comment: *doing so seems like a complicated and long calculation* Lots of calculations in GR are long and complicated. In general, there is no reason to expect them to be simple. I don’t know whether this one can be made easier.

Comment: *I am interested in finding the field equations* The relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_gravity) has them, although not a derivation.

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2186) says that its reference 1 has the derivation. See the top of the page with page number 4.

Comment: The field equations are just $B_{\mu \nu}=0$, where $B$ is the Bach tensor.

Comment: These days, you can easily find the equations of motion of such a Lagrangian by using tensor computer algebra packages like xAct.

Answer (score 0):

The integral can be rewritten as $$L=\int \sqrt{-g}C^{abcd} C_{abcd} d^4x=\int \sqrt{-g}(R^{ab}R_{ab}- \frac{1}{3}R^2)d^4 x$$. However, the variation of the first term $\int \sqrt{-g}R^{ab}R_{ab}d^4 x$ according to the article "Alternatives to dark matter and Dark energy" contains a Ricci scalar term. I have no ideal how the Ricci scalar term is from.